# How to get the exact sale amount in Salesforce ios

Tags: ios

Is there a field that returns the exact sale amount in salesforce?. Currently, i'm using the "Amount" from "Opportunity". I want to get the exact Amount (ex. 1,234.00) not the estimated amount.

Answer (score 0):

Can't Find a field so i just formatted the result from Amount:

```
-(NSString *) convertAmount:(NSNumber *) number{
if ([number isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    number = 0;
}
unsigned long long value = [number longLongValue];

NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; // to get commas (or locale equivalent)

NSString *result = [fmt stringFromNumber:@(value)];
result = [result stringByAppendingString:@".00"];

return result;
}
```

And to use it:

```
NSString * TestingVal = [self convertAmount:VALUE_FETCHED];
NSLog(@"Amount Value: %@", TestingVal);
```

Comment: A few things to point out here: first, it is expensive to re-create `NSNumberFormatter` objects and you should cache them, especially in cases like this where you are converting many numbers. Second, `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle` is likely to give you better currency results especially for non-USD values. Third, you have an extra unnecessary cast to `unsigned long long` and back again to `NSNumber` via the boxed `@(value)` when you would be better off formatting the raw `NSNumber` itself.

Comment: I see. Good point @Jonathan
Thanks